# Cannot open input file 'ANN.lib' in QT creator 4.21(community)

Tags: qt, linker, nearest-neighbor

ANN: Approximate Nearest Neighbor Searching.

I am using QT creator in windows-10 64 bit system. I have compiled the source files from official site of ANN with visual studio 2015 and have successfully run the sample and test with the same environment. That is also the way how I get dll and lib files.

However, I tried to add the library to my QT creator but failed. I used both external library and internal library, even tried system library, but the problem of ' cannot open' always shows up. Meanwhile, I tried put all .h files, dll and lib file in the project's directory, still the same problem. All of other external libraries work fine after I configure them in my qmake file. Here is an example:

```
LIBS += -lopengl32
```

This is an internal lib I added (maybe system lib). And:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.0/ -lboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_63
-llibboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-s-1_63
-llibboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-1_63
-llibboost_system-vc140-mt-s-1_63
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release):
LIBS += -LC:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.0/
INCLUDEPATH += C:/local/boost_1_63_0
DEPENDPATH += C:/local/boost_1_63_0
```

As you can see, the two above libraries are working perfectly. Again, as I mentioned, my VS2015 can compile the sample by the library I put in the system directories. So how should I configure ANN lib in my QT?

Comment: Have you tried `LIBS += -Lc:/path/to/ann/folder -lann`? Have you compiled the library with the same compiler (ex. 32 vs 64bit)?

Comment: Yes I have tried that way as external library. I created a folder to dist C and put everything in it, then used the instruction you mentioned. The ANN.lib was selected by me and it automatically selected the include files. But still the same problem... I am so confused. Btw, I compile the library with VS2015-64 by 'Win32 Release', and my QT is also 64bit.

Comment: I was trying to compile through VS2015 'x64 Release'. DLL and ANN.lib are updated to the specific directories. But still the same...

Comment: I tried again to put them as external library after the 64 version of ANN.lib was generated. And it works correctly now... Thank you for answering..

Comment: You may formulate an answer yourself. It may be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the main part of this problem by the suggestion made by the dude who commented above. Thanks a lot! The situation currently is that I can run the `ANN.lib` correctly in my QT creator with several other libraries (without compiling errors).

As I mentioned, I have already put all necessary files into the system directories, such as dll(`system32`), .lib(`my visual studio 14/VC/lib`), .h(`my visual studio 14/VC/include`). But that seemed not enough to run the `ANN.lib` successfully.

So I added a configuration of compilation, which is x64 release, to generate the newest dll and lib. Then I did the last step again, still not working. After that I put all files in single directory located in disk C and add this path to my qmake as external library. Now it works. Although I didn't delete the ones in my system's directories, it is running. Another thing I wonder to mention is that I also add this path to environment variables, so that I can just use `+= -lANN` to run the lib without making it as external library. Both can work fine.